# Navigation drawer Items not registering click event

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, navigation-drawer

I am struggling to get the Navigation drawer items to register and start and intent for a new activity.
The drawer opens fine and is displayed correctly but nothing happens when I click on the items in the list. 
Here is my code that is taken from the google tutorials.

```
mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
           mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
           mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
           mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

           // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
           mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
           // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
           mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                   R.layout.drawer_list_item, mTitles));
           mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

           // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
           getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

           // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
           // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
           mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                   this,                  /* host Activity */
                   mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                   R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                   R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                   R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                   ) {
               public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                   getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                   invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
               }

               public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                   getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                   invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
               }
           };
           mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

          // if (savedInstanceState == null) {
               selectItem(0);
           }


       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       }

       /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
       @Override
       public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
           boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
         //  menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
           return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
            // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
           if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
               return true;
           }
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);       
           }


       /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
       private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               selectItem(position);
           }
       }

       private void selectItem(int position) {
           switch (position) {
           case 1:
               new DataTask(MainActivity.this).execute();   
               MainActivity.this.finish();//Set this Activity to Finish so no loop back       
               Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SplashScreen.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               break;
           case 2:
              // ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragment());
            //  setTitle("Second");
               break;
           case 3:
              // ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment());
            //   setTitle("Third");
               break;

           default:
               break;
           }
           // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
           mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
           //setTitle(mTitles[position]);
           mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
       }

       @Override
       public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
           mTitle = title;
           getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
       }

       /**
        * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
        * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
        */

       @Override
       protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
           mDrawerToggle.syncState();
       }

       @Override
       public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
           super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
           // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
           mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       }

       /**
        * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
        */
       public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
           public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

           public PlanetFragment() {
               // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
           }

         //  @Override
        /*   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
               int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
               String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

               int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                               "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
               ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
               getActivity().setTitle(planet);
               return rootView;                      */
           }
```

If you can provide any help that would be great as I am really pulling my hair out on this. Thank you.

Comment: Is your selectItem() method being called?

Comment: Yes it is as the activity starts? but not when I click a list item.

Comment: I do not know where the error occurs but I would let my Activity implement the _ListView.OnItemClickListener_ , set the onClickListener of the ListView to _this_ and implement the _onItemClick()_ method in your activity instead of a seperate class.

Comment: Thanks for your help, ok, how would I get a reference to the item clicked?

Comment: if you don't get your answer yet post xml file, I think can help you, because i had this problem too and I fix that

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The problem is the z ordering. When you expand the list in `onDrawerOpened` put:

```
mDrawerList.bringToFront();
mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
```

In this post explain the problem and how fix it:
http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/android-custom-navigation-drawer-not.html

Comment: 1st line seems to be enough for me.

Comment: i have tried alot  over net for two days.. finally  this solution is perfect.. Thank you very much

Comment: bringToFront(); solved the problem..you saved my day :)

Comment: bringToFront() method was the saviour for me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this helped me and is still relevant.

Comment: Man you are genius +1

Answer (score 15):

Fixed a similar issue by adding `drawerView.bringToFront();` to

```
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

}
```

Comment: in addition, this function can be find using : 
mDrawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() { ... });
require support-v4-23.2+

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list in Navigation Drawer then just write the code and make listview clickable:

```
list.bringToFront();
drawerLayout.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you have `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` attribute on ListView parent(in layout resource).
Removing that attribute worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the your `DrawerItemClickListener.class` does not work as the only time the `selectItem()` method is called is at the end of your activities `onCreate()` at `selectItem(0);`

Instead of calling

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

you can use `this` as a parameter and let you `Activity` implement the `ListView.OnItemClickListener` itself.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        [...]
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        [...]
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        [...]
     }

    [...]    

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                [...]
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class));
                break;
            [...]
            default:
            break;
        }
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, No unfortunately that doesn't seem to  have solved it? any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with not responding on clicks navigation driver. Somehow I have found a solution: problem was in XML file. I used this and my problem was gone:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffff"/>
```

hope this will be usefull.