# Android - Navigation Drawer to implement activity changing

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've been reading a lot of questions and tutorials in regards to implementing a Navigation Drawer to change between Fragments. For this question, these implementations are not wanted as I wish to change from one activity, to the next.

I've implemented a custom Sidebar Adaptor with extends `ArrayAdapter<String>`. This allows to to implement my own styling to my navigation drawer. See the first code snippet below.

```
public class SidebarAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    String data[] = null;

    public SidebarAdaptor(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] data)
    {
        // Initiate the ArrayAdapter
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);

        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ControlHolder holder;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ControlHolder();
            TextView control = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
            holder.control = control;

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ControlHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        String text = data[position];
        holder.control.setText(text);

        return row;
    }

    static class ControlHolder
    {
        TextView control;
    }

}
```

This adapter is then set in the `onCreate` function in my `MainActivity` class. See below.

```
private void customiseSidebar() {
        SidebarAdaptor sidebarAdaptor = new SidebarAdaptor(
                this,
                R.layout.side_bar_custom_row,
                new String[]{"Login", "Offline Access", "Register", "Forgotten Password"}
        );

        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);

        listView1.setAdapter(sidebarAdaptor);
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}
```

The `DrawerItemClickListener` class then holds what activity to switch to once the user pressed any of the options in the Navigation Drawer. See the final code snippet below.

```
package ap.classes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import ap.ForgottenPassword;
import apMainActivity;
import ap.OfflineAccess;
import ap.RegisterAccount;

public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);

        }

            /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
        private void selectItem(int position) {

            switch(position)
            {
                case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OfflineAccess.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterAccount.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForgottenPassword.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

        }
    }
```

Now I seem to be having three quite substantial issues:

1. The first being the following error message: `MainActivity is not an enclossing class`
2. The second states that it; `Cannont resolve method startActivity in android.content.Intent`
3. The final issue is, as soon as I click anything in the NavigationDrawer, the drawer then closes without any keypresses being registered.

Thank you Stackoverflow.

Comment: The third issue can be fixed by changing the Z-Ordering on the ListView control.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941570/navigation-drawer-items-not-registering-click-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix first two issues:

> The first being the following error message: MainActivity is not an enclossing class
>
> The second states that it; Cannont resolve method startActivity in android.content.Intent

According to code you provided you are not in the scope of the Activity class when making call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OfflineAccess.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

above tells compiler to call method DrawerItemClickListener.startActivity(Intent intent), and there is no such method. Instead you should pass instance of an activity and call its *startActivty* method.

Second one *MainActivity is not an enclossing class* error is thrown because of usage *MainActivity.this* instead of passing instance of context.

To sum up you could do:

```
public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    private Activity mActivity;
    public DrawerItemClickListener(Activity activity){
        mActivity = activity;
    }

        /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {

        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, OfflineAccess.class);
            mActivity.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        /.../

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This has been fixed now, but I still have an issue with the first statement in my OP. Any ideas why?

Comment: Fixed issue three, see comment in OP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i had faced similar problem.While Fragments with navigation drawer it will be easy but using Activity. You must create a Custom Navigation Drawer. I give my idea.`enter code here`

```
public class DrawerItemClickListener extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    private List<DrawerList> drawerListList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentView());

        drawerListList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();

    }

    protected abstract int getContentView();

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        drawerListList.add(new DrawerList("1", R.drawable.1));
        drawerListList.add(new DrawerList("2", R.drawable.2));
        drawerListList.add(new DrawerList("3", R.drawable.3));
        drawerListList.add(new DrawerList("4", R.drawable.4));
        drawerListList.add(new DrawerList("5", R.drawable.5));

        CustomDrawerAdapter adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_menu, drawerListList);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    if (id == 0) {
                        intent = new Intent(DrawerItemClickListener .this, FirstActivity.class);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        onDrawerClose();
                    } else if (id == 1) {
                        intent = new Intent(DrawerItemClickListener .this, SecondActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        onDrawerClose();
                    } else if (id == 2) {

                        intent = new Intent(DrawerItemClickListener .this, ThirdActivity.class);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        onDrawerClose();
                    } else if (id == 3) {
                        intent = new Intent(DrawerItemClickListener .this, FouthActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        onDrawerClose();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    public void onDrawerClose() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And Custom Adapter is below

```
public class CustomDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerList> {
    private Context context;
    private List<DrawerList> drawerItemList;
    private int layoutResID;

    public CustomDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID, List<DrawerList> listItems) {
        super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
        this.context = context;
        this.drawerItemList = listItems;
        this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
            drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);
            drawerHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);

            view.setTag(drawerHolder);

        } else {
            drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        DrawerList dItem = this.drawerItemList.get(position);
        drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(dItem.getMenuImage()));
        drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getMenuName());

        return view;
    }

    private static class DrawerItemHolder {
        TextView ItemName;
        ImageView icon;
    }
}
```

And you extend it from each activity like

```
public class FirstActivity extends DrawerItemClickListener {
..
}
```

And also Listview Added in each xml layout.
Hope It will be helpful.

Comment: Is all of this code completely necessary? Also, I'm struggling to understand each and every bit of it.