# Android navigationview with header set , onItemClick not working

Tags: android

I'm developing an application (as my first one) and In this app I've declared my navigationView like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
     app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header">
```

In my mainactivity.java I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
...
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Log.d("Navigation","Item selected : "+ item.getItemId());
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.about:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"About Us 
   elected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.help:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"Help",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.setting:

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 "Settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.EditProfile:{
            Intent intent= new Intent(this , EditProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) 
findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return false;
}
```

And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536187/4158832) I've extended `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and in it's `onDrawerOpened` function I've don

```
drawerView.bringToFront();
drawerView.getParent().requestLayout();
```

But still when I click on navigation view Items onNavigationItemSelected function doesn't fire.

Is it because of header view I have added??

This method worked before I add header view to navigationView( I didn't test it just before adding header to navigationView.

And also I think it's useful to note that I have some buttons and TextViews in navigationView header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_header"
    android:background="@drawable/drawer_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar"
            android:id="@+id/AvatarImageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:text="Signup"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/header_signup"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:background="@drawable/signup_button"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header_username"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Logout"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header_logout"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add following line of code in `onCreate` for click listener for menu item,

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id. navigation_drawer);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: That's done before.Just because onCreate function was a large one I didn't write the details of it.

Comment: That is the only line we should use for NavigationView item click, May be you can add your complete code or you can add you log if you find anything different which click.

Comment: Pardon me.
I checked the code again and I found that I had forgotten to add
`navigationView.setNavigatoinItemSelectedListener(this);`
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can set click listener to the header of the NavigationView like this:

```
View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        headerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent intent= new Intent(this , EditProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
});
```

and for the elements inside the header

```
 CircleImageView   userPicture = (CircleImageView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.AvatarImageView);
```

**Edit**

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: My header elements are working good.My menu Items that I've defined `@menu/drawer_menu` aren't working.

Comment: navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
  path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/";
   File f= new File(path);
```